# Overriding biblatex verbose style abbreviated citation

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with the verbose citation style. In one instance I need to force an abbreviated footnote citation back to the original (long) form. My guess is that I need to reset or override a flag or setting. I only wish to do that for one reference, in one specific location, leaving all other things alone.

TIA
Nigel

Comment: you can use the `\fullcite{key}` command

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I mark this as answered? I can see no check box or similar next to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can print full citings with the command `\fullcite{key}` or `\footfullcite{key}` for footnotes. It will print the same informations as you will get in the bibliography.

See manual, 3.7.6 Special Commands